# Haskell - Create thread, write to screen, sleep thread, write something else to screen

Tags: multithreading, haskell

I'm having difficulty creating something basic in Haskell.

I'm trying to create new thread and write something to the screen, sleep, then write something else to the screen.

I think i'm supposed to be using the forkIO but i'm unsure how to structure the statement.

Thanks in advance to anyone who could help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: your idea is right - you can do this with [`forkIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:forkIO) - the function you can use to let your thread sleep for a while is [`threadDelay`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:threadDelay) (you have to use *micro*seconds! - usually it's only *milli*seconds, so watch out)

The easiest way is to embed the `forkIO` right into your computation (`main` here) - Here is a quick snippet that will do as you ask:

```
module Main where

import Control.Concurrent

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "press Enter to exit the program"
  threadId <- forkIO $ do
    putStrLn "Something"
    threadDelay 5000000 -- wait 5 seconds
    putStrLn "Something Else"
  _ <- getLine
  return ()
```

if you compile this with `-threaded`:

```
ghc Main.hs -threaded
```

if should print the first line then wait 5sec. and finally print the second line.

### remarks

- The last `getLine` is there as a poor mans *wait for the thread* - so you have to end the program by pressing  (without this there would be no output as the program ends with the main thread)
- `threadId` is the [`ThreadId`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#t:ThreadId) of the thread you just *started* - have a look at the [`Control.Concurrent` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html) to see some ways to interact with that

Maybe you don't like to have this inside `main` - if so you can just refactor it out too (this might yield cleaner code):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "press Enter to exit the program"
  threadId <- forkIO myThreadComputation
  _ <- getLine
  return ()

myThreadComputation :: IO ()
myThreadComputation = do
    putStrLn "Something"
    threadDelay 5000000 -- wait 5 seconds
    putStrLn "Something Else"
```

Comment: Is the `hSetBuffering` bit really needed? The default for compiled programs is `LineBuffering`, which should be fine. (ghci defaults to `NoBuffering`, which when combined with `interact`/`putStr` is a common source of confusion when switching from testing in ghci to compiling the program, but since everything here is already using `putStrLn` there should be little observable difference between the two buffering styles.)

Comment: @DanielWagner to be honest I was not 100% sure - I tend to test my things (using emacs/eshell when I am on windows) and practically auto-insert this  just to be sure (because I had issues before) - but to be sure I retested it right now and **you are right**  I don't need it in GHCi - but in eShell/compiled/Windows without it I will see the output only after I input the `getLine` - the normal Windows prompt works fine so I guess I can safely remove it - sorry for this confustion