# extracting seconds from UTCTime and asynchronously sleep

Tags: haskell

```
syncClockTime :: TimeZone -> UTCTime -> Pico -> Pico
syncClockTime zone time secondTo = do
    let (TimeOfDay hour minute secondFrom) = localTimeOfDay $ utcToLocalTime zone time
    if secondTo > secondFrom then
        secondTo - secondFrom
    else
        60 + secondTo - secondFrom
```

I have a couple of questions related to the above code

1. is there a way to directly extract the seconds `secondFrom` from the `UTCTime` **without** converting it to local time and **without** specifying a time zone? (if yes: how? if no: why?)
2. How to actually make the running thread/task to **asynchronously sleep** for the above found number of seconds?

Comment: What do you mean by "asynchronously sleep"?

Comment: Why is there a `do` in the `syncClockTime`?

Comment: I don't know F# or C#.

Comment: So ... synchronous sleep? That's `threadDelay`.

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482958/haskell-convert-utctime-to-seconds-and-milliseconds and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35477808/haskell-create-thread-write-to-screen-sleep-thread-write-something-else-to, so it's probably too broad.

Comment: `UTCTime` doesn't have a separate seconds component. It stores a day number and the number of picoseconds since midnight.

Comment: @user1892538: `do` has *nothing* to do with `if`-`then`-`else`. `if`-`then`-`else` in fact just maps on the `ifThenElse :: Bool -> a -> a -> a` function. `do` is used as syntactical sugar for a monad (e.g. `IO` monad).

Answer (score 2):

Question 2 is simple: you can make your Haskell process sleep for a specified number of microseconds using [`delay`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/concurrent-extra-0.5/docs/Control-Concurrent-Thread-Delay.html).

If I understand your Question 1, you want to be able to specify, say 30 seconds, and wait until the next time the system clock is 30 seconds past the minute. So if you call your function at 13:23:27 it will wait 3 seconds until 13:23:30, but if you called it at 13:23:33 then it will wait 57 seconds until 13:24:30.

That is a matter of doing arithmetic on the number of seconds. I would suggest you take the current Posix time using [`getPOSIXTime`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/time-1.8.0.2/Data-Time-Clock-POSIX.html#t:POSIXTime). This returns a `NominalDiffTime`, which is an instance of `Real` and `RealFrac`, so normal arithmetic works fine. The code you want is:

```
t <- getPOSIXTime
let secs = t - fromIntegral (floor (t/60) * 60)
```

Once you have the number of seconds past the minute you can figure out how long to wait until your target time.

Comment: Not sure about the distinction you are making between sync and async, but if you only have one thread then "delay" will sleep your entire process. I don't know about .Net threads, but Haskell threads are indeed very light.

Comment: @user1892538: "mod" only works with integral types. The formula I gave does the equivalent of "mod", but with fractional types.